# Is it possible to safely make a tuple of lvalue references for an aggregate object using fewer than three declarations?

Tags: c++, tuples

I want to support some method, preferably named `tie()`, on my aggregate classes to allow callers to leverage various functionality involving `std::tuple` objects.  The functionality is not limited to what is provided in the standard library.

My best attempt at a safe and fully featured implementation requires three overloads, as shown below.

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;

    auto tie() const & { return std::tie(s1, s2); }
    auto tie() & { return std::tie(s1, s2); }
    // auto tie() && = delete;
};

int main()
{
    auto refs = Foo{"this is a long string", ""}.tie();
    std::cout << std::get<0>(refs); // <- prints garbage
    return 0;
}
```

I rejected `std::make_tuple` due to performance concerns.  Is there a better way to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: What exactly are the performance concerns of `std::make_tuple`? Are you talking about compile times?

Comment: @BrianBi, my primary concern is non-trivial copy construction of members.  In the code I included, the two `std::string` objects are copied.  Even with a stack allocated string, a copy will take place with `std::make_tuple`, but not with `auto tie()`

Answer (score 0):

The following technique achieves the desired outcome.

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    friend auto tie(auto& foo) { return std::tie(foo.s1, foo.s2); }
};

int main()
{
    auto foo = Foo{"", ""};
    auto refs = tie(foo);
    static_assert(std::tuple_size_v<decltype(refs)> == 2);
    auto stdrefs = std::tie(foo);
    static_assert(std::tuple_size_v<decltype(stdrefs)> == 1);
    tie(Foo{"",""}); // cannot bind non-const lvalue reference error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work for templated types

Comment: Nor for different types (`struct Foo` and `struct Bar`) (without big changes). Deducing-this of C++23 might help.